# Host Network on Swarm: Service Discovery and Communication with other Services

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I’ve been working with Docker Swarm and have run into an issue regarding service discovery. Specifically, one of my services is utilizing the “host network”, and I’ve learned from a discussion on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/27) that I’m unable to simultaneously include my service in the overlay network.

This situation has created a significant roadblock for me because it has prevented the use of Docker Swarm’s DNSRR feature. Previously, I leveraged DNSRR for service discovery, particularly for identifying the IPs of active tasks.I am seeking a solution or feature that allows me to query all the tasks currently running under the service, including their private and/or public IPs.

Furthermore, when my service was attached to the overlay network, I was able to directly access other services using their DNS names. However, now that my service isn’t a part of the overlay network, I am compelled to use private IPs, which isn’t optimal.

Could anyone point me in the direction of a solution or workaround for these challenges? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have tried to add my service into the overlay network but it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot have both `host` and another network because of a limitation of Docker Swarm.  What you can do is the following assuming you have `traefik`.

Run two services:

1. `traefik` for external

   a. runs and listens to port 80/443 on host mode networking.

   b. it is only on host network

   c. I'm assuming you'd have a reroute so HTTP goes to HTTPS
   d. Route HTTPS over to the other traefik
2. `traefik` for Docker swarm overlay

   a. runs on overlay network

   b. get the real IP from `external-traefik`

   c. exposed on a different port e.g. `8443`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ultimately decided to use Consul. The services running on the host network automatically register themselves upon startup. I then retrieve the service IPs by querying the Consul API.